# XPages richtext field doesn't work on mobile

Tags: xpages, rich-text-editor

I am working on an XPage application with few richtexts field on a page. It works well on desktop, however, the richtext field just doesnt show up on mobile environment. Here's a public link for testing (it would show up a richtext field when opened on a desktop but would just show up a small empty box on an mobile - tested on safari, chrome, default android browser):

[XPage Application With RichText Field](http://teamground.de/test.nsf)

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Mobile cannot cope with the CK Editor, so Rich Text cannot be edited on mobile. This is still the case with 9.0.1, from my experience on a recent training course. But I believe the Dojo editor works on iOS. I can't find the blog post and it was from a couple of years ago, but I found that the XPages forum was working by using the Dojo rich text editor instead of the default CK Editor. I can't remember if that was on 8.5.3 or 9.0 though.

Comment: ok, I will give a shot to dojo Rich Text editor in that case. However, in that case, I won't have an option to bind the field, right? or it still works like a normal xpage control?

Comment: No, it's the normal Rich Text Editor field with the relevant dojo type. It may be "ibm.domino.widget.layout.DominoRichText" (you'll also need to include that Dojo module on the page), though I'm not sure

Comment: Found the blog post where I identified this http://www.intec.co.uk/lotusphere-day-2-review/. I'm not sure if it works on 8.5.3, but it's also going to depend on the mobile platform in use.

Comment: So, based on the blog post, I believe that, irrespective of the domino version it should work with dojo editor, I will give it a try soon..thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If I view the source on your link I see that you have Dojo 1.6.1 and that means to me that you are using Domino 8.5.3

The richtext editor didn't work with older versions of Domino in mobile.
you need to upgrade to Domino 9 or preferable 9.0.1 with the latest [Extlib from openntf](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/requests)

Comment: Yes, you are right, its 8.5.3, I will ask our administrator to update it soon to see the result, till then(possibly a week), I have to wait to accept the answer(though I am hoping that this solves the issue)... thanks a lot :)